# bring spefic record from query to form in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form of table of people.
I Have another form of tests and the people who tested.
I have a query that give me the names of all the people and if the average grade of some people is over 55, it gives me PASSED OR NO PASSED.

Now , i made a form of the table of people,
And I want to bring the Grade (*PASSED OR NOT*) from the query to the form.
I have no idea how to do that.
I tried to the some text box with "`=[qry]![Grade]`"
but it gives me "`#NAME?`" Error.

Anyone has an idea ? Thanks.
I Use Microsoft access 2016.

STUDENTS table fields -
Name
Age
Class

TESTS table fields -
Name of student,
Name of test,
Grade

Query fields - comes from tests table --
Name of student,
PASSED/ NOT PASSED

FORM fields-
All the fields of students table, passed or not from the query

Comment: Does the recordset for this form have the grade field?

Comment: just the qurey has the grade field And i want to bring it to my form

Comment: Have you tried in properties of the form change the data source to this query

Comment: Data source of the field or the form ?

Comment: The form first, then the Textbox relating to Grade

Comment: But all the fields of the forms come from the table, just the grade field comes from the query

Comment: Can you post the table fields and the fields of the query in your question?

Comment: Which table does the query come from?

Comment: I just edited my original post with the fields

Comment: What is the name of the query?

Comment: Is there any relationship between test table and students?

Comment: Yes , the name of the student

Comment: This relationship is 1-1 or 1-many?

Comment: 1 to many .. Every student has a couple of tests

Comment: I just post a possible answer, see if it works

Answer (score 0):

- If the table Students and Tests are in Relationship and you want display their fields in a Single form:

First, edit your query: the tables for this query should be both Students and Tests.

Select the fields from Students and Tests to this query.

Open the form in design mode and change the data source of the form to the referred query.

The textbox data source you want display the field Grade from Table Tests should be set Grade

- If the data you need is only on Tests Table:

Open the form in design mode and change the data source of the form to the Tests table.

- If you want a Form with subform, as the main form shows the data from Students and the subform shows their Tests data

As you mentioned, the form is already set the data source with Students Table. don't change it.

Create a subform inside the Form with the subform data source = Tests, then show the relationship each Tests have to each Students

---

Above are the possibilities you have, you can try the one is more easy to you or suitable what you want.

If you want a Relationship between Students and Tests, it is recommendable, set in Students a primary key and in Tests one Field that can relate to Students' primary key.

In Ms access, Tables are designed to store data, but with queries is more powerful, they can Select data from more than on Table, for example (since it has a Relationship between them)

Comment: What do you mean that the tables for the query should be both students and tests ? 
I have all the details in tests table, what do i need students table also ?

Comment: @Noam If you need the fields Age and Class from Students, include this table in Query along Tests. But if you need only Tests, change the form Data Source to Tests